# Convergene of a sequence if and only if limsup and liminf agree

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

This is in terms of sets (within the context of probability measure theory) if that matters. The book says "this is equivalent" without proof, I want to prove the gap!

Indicator function of a set $A$ is defined as: $\mathbb{I}_A(\omega)=1$ if $\omega\in A$  else $=0$ defined over all of $\Omega$, basically it's a function that is 1 over $A$ and 0 elsewhere.

Let $\{A_n\}$ be a sequence of subsets of $\Omega$ inside the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ (this just means it is closed under countable union and intersections)

$A_n\rightarrow A$ ($A_n$ is said to converge) if $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(\mathbb{I}_{A_n})=\mathbb{I}_A$

Limsup and liminf are defined as follows

$\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}(A_n)=\cap^\infty_{n=1}(\cup_{i=n}^\infty A_i)$
$\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}(A_n)=\cup^\infty_{n=1}(\cap_{i=n}^\infty A_i)$

The claim is $A_n\rightarrow A\iff A=\limsup(A_n)=\liminf(A_n)$

I've tagged this "Real analysis" because that's where I learnt about limits, and consider the definition of them to be under its umbrella.

**What have I tried?**

I'm struggling to get started, I'm not sure if I should be looking at the limit of the indicator function pointwise or as a function, and if so how to consider it in those separate lights, and then use the information from limsup and liminf to show the result.

So I need to more carefully define the limit of the indicator function (does it start: $\forall\omega\in\Omega\forall\epsilon>0$ or does it start $\forall\epsilon>0\forall\omega\in\Omega$) then get that in terms of the limsup and liminf.

I can see glimpses of the proof but evidently cannot formulate it entirely. I'd love some clearing up.

I've spotted similar questions just now and I shall read those, I would none the less like to know how I should be treating convergence of a function, point-wise or not.

Comment: What is your definition of $\lim A_n=A$? In this cases, it usually is $\limsup A_n=\liminf A_n$.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I want to show the one using the indicator function is equivalent to limsup=liminf and that limit is = them both. $A_n$ converges to $A$ if the indicator function of $A_n$ converges to the indicator function of $A$

Comment: Oh, OK. What have you tried? Do you know that $\liminf A_n=\{x:x\in A_n$ for all but finitely $n\}$ and that $\limsup A_n=\{x:x\in A_n$ for all $n$ in an infinite $N\subseteq \Bbb N\}$?

Comment: I didn't @PedroTamaroff but that seems fairly close to the definitions I gave and I could (very probably) get there without help. So consider it known!

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I've browsed around and made some more attempts, I'm really struggling with "pointwise convergence" or "convergence of the function (and defining that)" then getting that into a format I can plug limsup and liminf into I'd really like some help and this isn't the "easy" kind of question that usually gets an answer, so please do!

Answer (score 2):

Assume $A_n \to A$ in the sense that $\mathbb{I}_{A_n}(\omega) \to \mathbb{I}_{A}(\omega) \quad \forall \omega \in \Omega$.

The sequence which has only zeros and ones as its terms will converge if and only if the sequence eventually becomes either zeros (that is, after some $n$ all the terms will be zeros) or ones

Now, assume $\omega \in A$. Then $\mathbb{I}_{A}(\omega) = 1$ which means there exists $n$ such that $\omega \in A_k \quad \forall k > n$ which implies that $A \subset \liminf A_n$.

Now assume that $\omega \in A^c$. Then $\mathbb{I}_{A}(\omega) = 0$ which means there exists $n$ such that $\omega \in A_k^c \quad \forall k > n$ which implies that $A^c \subset \liminf A_n^c$ which means $\limsup A_n \subset A$.

Using the above two results, we have $A = \limsup A_n = \liminf A_n$

The other direction of the result follows using similar ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that your $A_i$, $A$ are all subsets of a set $X$. Suppose first that for each $x\in X$, we have that $1_{A_n}(x)\longrightarrow 1_A(x)$. Since $1_{A_n}$ takes the value $0$ or $1$, this means that for each $x\in X$ there is $N(x)=N$ such that $1_{A_n}(x)$ is constant for $n>N$ with value $1$ or $0$, and it equals $1_A(x)$. It is always the case that $A_*\subseteq A^*$ (I'm being lazy to denote the limit inferior and limit superior). Thus, it suffices to show that that $A^*\subseteq A_*$, that is, it suffices we show that if there is an infinite subset $S\subseteq \Bbb N$ such that $x\in \bigcap_S A_{n}$; then $x\in A_*$.

Now, since $S$ is infinite, we can pick $M\in S$ larger that $N(x)$. This means that $1=1_{A_n}(x)=1_{A_N}(x)$ for every $n>N$ (because we know that the sequence is constant!), so that $x\in \bigcap_{n\geqslant N}A_n$, so $x\in A_*$. In fact $A=A*=A_*$.

For the converse, it should be immediate to see that if $A=A*=A_*$ then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} A_n= A$