# Pointwise limit of an indicator function

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Given $f_{k}(x) = k\mathbf{1}_{(0,\frac{1}{k}]}(x)$ I wanted to compute the limit as $k \to \infty$.

Is the following correct:

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x \notin (0, \frac{1}{k}]$ then for $N \in \mathbb{N}$, sufficiently large (e.g. $N > x$) we have $\mathbf{1}_{(0, \frac{1}{k}]}(x) = 0$ and this holds for all $n \geq N$.

Therefore the pointwise limit is $0$.

Note: As per comments this has been addressed as not being correct and I have amended it.

Follow up question:

If I calculate the $\lim_{k \to \infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_{k} d\mu $ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\lim_{k \to \infty}f_{k}d\mu$ where $d\mu$ is Lebesgue measure I obtain two different values. Graphing the function it is clear that the dominated convergence theorem cannot apply, because there is no "dominating" function. I'm assuming (since I get two different values), that the monotone convergence theorem also cannot apply, but I can't work out why. From what I can see, $f_{k}(x) \leq f_{k+1}(x), \forall x$ and we know that the pointwise limit exists...

Comment: No that's not correct.  You can't have $x$ depend on $k$.  You must fix an arbitrary $x$ and then let $k\to\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pointwise limit is indeed $0$ for every $x$ but your "proof" is opaque when it comes to the use of indices $k,N,n$.

The intention might be okay, but I would not classify it as a correct proof.

The essence is that it can be proved that for every $x\in\mathbb R$ some positive integer $n$ exists with: $$k\geq n\implies x\notin(0,\frac1k)$$

That implies directly that for every $x\in\mathbb R$ some positive integer $n$ exists with: $$k\geq n\implies f_k(x)=0$$ hence for every $x\in\mathbb R$: $$\lim_{k\to\infty}f_k(x)=0$$

---

**edit**:

We do *not* have $f_k\leq f_{k+1}$ here because for  $x\in\left(\frac1{k+1},\frac1{k}\right]$ we have $f_{k+1}(x)=0<f_k(x)$.

Comment: Having read the comments and attempting to fix my "proof": Fix $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Then there exists some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $k\geq n \Rightarrow x \notin (0, \frac{1}{k})$. Then as you put this directly implies the result. I have a follow up question around this function, is it okay to ask it here or should it be a new post? Thanks.

Comment: I would not mind if you ask it here in an update, and there are no other answers yet, so....  Make your own decision. Important is that you explicitly mention in your edit that it is a follow-up question.

Comment: thanks, I added an update.

Comment: @VBACODER I have edited in order to spread light on your second question.

Comment: thanks. I understand what you've put, but I don't understand why my thinking is wrong: We know $f_{k}(x)=k \mathbf{1}_{(0, \frac{1}{k}]}(x)$. Thus it equals $k$ if $x \in (0, \frac{1}{k}]$. So $f_{1}(x) = 1$ if $x \in (0,1]$ and $f_{2}(x) = 2$ if $x \in (0, \frac{1}{2}]$. Clearly $1 \leq 2$.

Comment: Ah, I think I realise where I went wrong. The inequality $f_{k} \leq f_{k+1}$ needs to hold for all $x$ and it doesn't.

Comment: Indeed. That is demanded if you want to apply MCT.